# Creating requests in fiddler2 gives a 401 unauthorized but the 200 negotiated request doesn't follow

Tags: json, fiddler

I'm trying to use fiddler to generate requests to receive a JSON response.  I drag a request that was captured from IE with a 200 response into the request builder then change the Accept header to "Accept: application/json".

After that I execute the request and get a 401 unauthorized response but the negotiation with a following 200 response does not take place.  If there another way I can get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason I was heading down this path was to track down why my AJAX requests against the SharePoint 2010 WCF data services were not returning data while using the .getJSON method in jQuery.  Turns out the SP2010 WCF data services escape single quotes in the JSON response.

Single quotes should not be escaped according to the [JSON spec](http://www.json.org/).